# C++: Is it possible to use dynamic binding with a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a template function which accepts a function-object ('functor') as a template parameter:

```
 template <typename Func> int f (void) {
    Func func;
    return func ();
};

struct Functor {
   virtual int operator () (void) = 0;
};

struct Functor0 : Functor {
    int operator () (void) {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct Functor1 : Functor  {
    int operator ()  (void) {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

I want to avoid an `if-else` block like:

```
int a;
if (someCondition) {
    a = f<Functor0> ();
}
else {
    a = f<Functor1> ();
}
```

Is there a way to use something similar to dynamic binding, i.e something like:

```
a = f<Functor> (); // I know this line won't compile, it is just an example of what I need
```

and decide in runtime what (derived) type is passed as the template parameter?

Comment: I don't see why templates are needed here - isn't this just a plain example of run-time polymorphism?

Comment: You could avoid the `if` / `else` with `a = someCondition ? f<Functor0>() : f<Functor1>();`

Comment: @unapersson - That's a good question - I an trying clean-up some existing code, and my question just popped into my head while doing so - I am sure it can be solved by using just polymorphism, but I wanted to know the answer anyway.
@Chris Lutz - that's just another syntax for `if/else`, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to use something similar to dynamic binding

No. This is fundamentally impossible. At some point in your code you need to have the case distinction. Of course, that doesn’t have to be written manually; you can use macros (or again templates) to generate the necessary code. But it needs to be there.

Answer (score 7):

One way to avoid the check (if that is REALLY what you want to do), is to use an array - ..

```
Functor* fp[] = { new Functor0(), new Functor1() };
```

now - use `someCondition` as an index.

```
a = (*fp[someCondition])();
```

this relies simply on run-time polymorphism rather than the redundant template mechanism you are using... (btw. don't forget to cleanup!)

Of course, this is nasty and frankly redundant, the overhead of the `if` will be insignificant, but the clarity it adds to the code is significant...

Comment: the cleanup could be avoided using `Functor const& fp[]` if the OP would make `operator()` `const` or using some smart pointers (`boost::scoped_ptr` / `std::unique_ptr`) otherwise.

Comment: @Matthieu M, for sure, I just wanted to highlight the approach, and indicate that it's most likely better to go for the `if` approach - purely because it's more straightforward to understand! :)